# Images are not validated when uploading an image with flask_uploads

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-uploads

I'm trying uploading an image with flask_uploads. When validation, it always shows that an image is required (it gets None rather than a FileStorage instance). 
I also tried different image types so that isn't due to the files.

Are there any missing? Many thanks.

**initialization**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'development'
app.config['UPLOADED_DEF_DEST'] = './static'
app.config['UPLOADED_DEF_URL'] = './static'

abc = UploadSet(name='DEF', extensions=IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, abc)
```

**views.py**

```
@main.route('/edit-profile', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def edit_profile():
    form = EditProfileForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        file_name = abc.save(form.btn_uploads.data)
        file_url = abc.url(file_name)
    return render_template('edit_profile.html', form=form)
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    btn_uploads = FileField(label='Profile Image', validators=[
        FileAllowed(abc, 'ONLY IMAGE ALLOWED'),
        FileRequired('IMAGE REQUIRED PLEASE')
    ])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

**edit_profile.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

{% block title %}Edit Profile{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Edit Your Profile</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you verify that the generated form in the page HTML has the enctype attribute set to "multipart/form-data"? https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html#form-macro-reference here it says that it should be set automatically if there's a FileField in the form definition, but just to be sure...

Comment: I also doubted this, but it should be set automatically if there's a FileField in the form definition as you mentions. I set `wtf.quick_form(form, enctype="multipart/form-data")`, and then it works. However, it still works without setting enctype in many cases. So I am wondering why this happen? I appreciate your comment :)

Comment: I quickly scanned trough the code and I think it's probably a bug in flask-bootstrap. I also found this bug report: https://github.com/mbr/flask-bootstrap/issues/177 . flask-bootstrap in turn uses this package to determine if there's a file field :https://pypi.org/project/visitor/  so I guess the bug is somewhere in the integration between the two...

Comment: @fabio.sussetto thank you for your kind help.